# Selenium Java Robot - How to Click on particular location(X,Y) of Firefox browser?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, java

I'm currently using a robot to click at a location on the screen as I've had issues with clicking a button that has a specific ID. e.g. Button_1401. This works fine up to a point, a few problems I've encountered so far have been scrolling the page/ a pop-up covering the browser/ screen resolution size.

I've been thinking of possibly moving the firefox window to the front before using the robot click each time but this seems like a slow process. Is it possible to tell the robot to click the X, Y of the browser itself?

I have tried using Actions.moveToElement but clicking the button even with the correct co-ordinates to offset to I get errors.

Comment: a robot = a script? a robot = robot framework?

Comment: a script? maybe I'm not sure to be honest, Just been trying things out and its worked so far

        Robot robot = new Robot();
        robot.mouseMove(151, 700);
        robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
        robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);

Comment: what exceptions did you get？

Comment: None, The code itself works for what I'm doing right now. the issue I was getting with Actions.moveToElement was about offsetting from a current static button to the ID specific button. Which would throw an exception of something like, the button you are trying to click 'button_1404' is not clickable. Im not really sure I tried it last week.

Answer (score 1):

There IS a way to click on a certain coordinates (X, Y), but you need to locate an element as the reference first.

Can you please try this approach?

```
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);   
builder.moveToElement(referenceElement, X, Y).click().build().perform();
```

where X and Y are the offsets from the reference element.

Comment: Hi, I had previously tried this. The button ID is Button_1404 but to the left of this is a button with a static ID of button 

I tried:
builder.moveToElement(button, 0, 100).click().build().perform();

but when the click is performed I get an error

Comment: sorry I mean 100, 0

Comment: This is what I tried previously       

       `WebElement link = driver.findElement(By.id("button"));
       Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
       builder.moveToElement(link, 200, 10).click().perform();
       builder.moveToElement(link, 200, 10).release().perform();`