# How to handle below slider option using Selenium Webdriver in java

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java

I can't imaging how to handle below type of slider option using selenium with java. There is no different xpaths for dropping locations. There should be different xpaths to use below option

```
Actions.dragAndDrop(Sourcelocator, Destinationlocator)
```

So how to handle this kind of one?[image]

DOM:
[image]

[image: [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qX1NO.png]

Comment: For us to provide any answer, can you add the DOM of this slider to your question? Without knowing how the HTML is setup, we can't provide answers.

Comment: Hey @LeeJensen.. added ss above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.click()` on that slider will click on the middle. If you want to click to the side, you can click using X, Y offsets. First get the width of the slider and then adjust your X coordinate accordingly. I used this trick (in C# anyway) for testing a "scrub bar" in a web video player by clicking on the second-to-last pixel of the slider and making sure the next video "auto-rolled".

Here is some sample code from [SQA StackExhange](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/a/20751/11015):

```
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);   
builder.moveToElement(referenceElement, X, Y).click().build().perform();
```

Comment: it works.. thanks